# inject recorded audio in an in-going call

Tags: adb, audio, calls

I need to inject a recorded voice during a live call to test the network, how can I do that?
I got a rooted device working on Qualcomm  MSM9889 soc.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57393147

Comment: @alecxs its also my question xD